# Why am I getting an ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid error when using the `joins` method on my model class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple rails app with the following models and associations:

```
# app/models/vendor.rb
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
end

# app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vendor, foreign_key: :account_id
  has_many :taxes
end

# app/models/tax.rb
class Tax
  belongs_to :product, foreign_key: :item_id
end
```

Why, when I run `Vendor.joins(:products)` in the console do I get the following error?

```
irb(main):039:0> Vendor.joins(:products)
  Vendor Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: products.vendor_id: SELECT  "vendors".* FROM "vendors" INNER JOIN "products" ON "products"."vendor_id" = "vendors"."id" LIMIT ?)
```

I also get a similar error when I try `Product.joins(:taxes)`. Does it have something to do with the foreign keys not being the default `..._id` maybe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `foreign_key` in the products table "pointing" to the vendors table is expected to be `vendor_id`, as Rails by convention prefixes the table name for foreign key constraints through tables and `joins` makes use of that column.

> From belongs_to Rails documentation:
>
> ... By default this is
>   guessed to be the name of the association with an “_id” suffix. So a
>   class that defines a belongs_to :person association will use
>   “person_id” as the default :foreign_key. Similarly, belongs_to
>   :favorite_person, class_name: "Person" will use a foreign key of
>   “favorite_person_id”.

What you can do is to "tell" Rails that the foreign_key to be used in the vendors table (Vendor model) is `account_id` instead of `vendor_id`.

Try with:

```
class Vendor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products, foreign_key: :account_id
  ...
end
```

---

Other way is just to create your own join:

```
Vendor.joins('INNER JOIN products ON products.account_id = vendors.id')
```